# Controlling Embedded System ( Product ) from Cloud

Tags: embedded, cloud

I am working on a simple linux based motor controlling project.
I have multiple systems like this. So, my main question is how I can identify and control these embedded systems from cloud. I have tested these embeded modules by connecting to a central server ( in same LAN only ). But, in that case I know the IP's of my embedded systems. If I deploy these modules in my client environment then the IP will be change.

So, I need help that how I can control and get status of these embedded systems.

Note: Most of these sysetems are connected in a LAN where the actual Public IP is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have the possibility, you could use static IP addresses (assigned by the DHCP server, based on the client's MAC address)
- Another possibility is using a local DNS server, which resolves local Domain Names (e.g.: Sensor1.that.company.local or ShadeMotor.company.intranet)

When accessing clients in a LAN from the parent WAN, you can either use port forwarding from the gateway, or a DMZ (Demilitarized Zone - all requests are forwarded to a single client, which redirects them if needed)
I'd either prefer the port forwarding method (given that your embedded systems are secure) or use a dedicated computer with at least a firewall and optionally packet content filtering as the DMZ target

Comment: Thank you very much.. But, It could not be possible to setup port forwarding or DMZ at all places right. So, I would like to know how any embedded device get command from cloud even if it is connected in a local lan with Internet connectivity

Comment: There is always a NAT when entering a subnet. If port-forwarding is not an option, you will definitely need

* some local server which is accessible from the internet
* a public accessible server, on which your modules can register